# Lost Windows 7 transparency DWM not working properly

Tags: windows-7, transparency, aero, dwm

After installing new theme from Microsoft (http://windows.microsoft.com/hr-HR/windows/downloads/snowflakes-and-frost-theme) my Windows 7 lost all its transparency (Aero) effects and placed Windows Basic as the actual theme.
I've been googling for my problem for an hour now and I have not found any solutions. 
All my attempts to fix this issue have failed.

1. I've tried running the standard wizard for for fixing transparency problems and I got a response:
   **Desktop Window Manager is disabled.** 
   The Desktop Window Manager service is running all the time. I can see dwm.exe in the list of active processes. I've tried stop/starting DWM and Themes service to no effect.
2. I've tried running system restore but it did not solve the problem.
3. I have Avast antivirus all the time and I have scanned the disk, there are no viruses.
4. I've installed newest drivers from ATI and this also did not help.

I just don't know what to do any more short of re-installing Windows (and that is something I will not do just to get some fancy transparency effects)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I've installed a third party extension which allows third party themes. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. This can be solved by the following:

1. Open `Services`. This can be done by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > `services.msc`.
2. Find `Desktop Window Manager Session Manager`.
3. Right click it and **`Start`** if not started, or **`Restart`** if started already.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Windows + R</kbd> -> Type in `msconfig`.
- Open *Services* tab.
- Click *Enable All* button.
- Then *Apply* button.
- Finally restart your computer and you get back everything in its place.